# How to display timestamp while scanning hbase?

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

```
for key, data in table.scan():
print('Found: {}, {}'.format(key, data))
```

I have an HBase table that I need to scan and print the timestamp. I have written the above code but it only produces output like...

> Found: b'row1', {b'cf1:col':(b'value')}

But I want output like...

> Found: b'row1', {b'cf1:col':(b'value', timestamp)}

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

By default, HBase does not include timestamps in the results you return. You can use HappyBase to retrieve them. To get them, your application needs to have `timestamps_include`,

```
row = table.row(b'row-key', columns=[b'cf1:col1'], include_timestamp=True)
value, timestamp = row[b'cf1:col1']
```

And after that, you can use,

```
for key, data in table.scan(include_timestamp=True):
   print('Found: {}, {}'.format(key, data))
```